# Fatal Error Joomla+Cron+Smart Search+Acepolls

Tags: php, joomla, ssh, cron

I try to set up automatic reindexing content in Joomla with module Smart Search.

http://docs.joomla.org/Setting_up_automatic_Smart_Search_indexing

Joomla 2.5.3

When i login by ssh to server and run script I get a fatal error... and save some posts (search index results on 8 pages).

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

```
* Processed batch 1 in 0.213 seconds.
* Processed batch 2 in 0.182 seconds.
* Processed batch 3 in 0.177 seconds.
* Processed batch 4 in 0.009 seconds.

PHP Fatal error: Class 'JModuleHelper' not found in / var / wolq.ru / plugins / content / acepolls / acepolls.php on line 41
Fatal error: Class 'JModuleHelper' not found in / var / wolq.ru / plugins / content / acepolls / acepolls.php on line 41
```

41-42 lines in acepolls.php:

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_acepolls');
$content = self::_renderModule($module, array(), $id);
```

If i run reindexing from web-interface - it's run succesfull and save search index results on 26 pages.

Comment: This is just a sidenote and it may not be directly related to your problem, but it would be great if you first upgraded to the latest version of Joomla!. Meanwhile bugs have been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havn't got the source code for mod_acepolls, so I'm not 100% about this but anyway:

Normally when running Joomla trough the web interface, Joomla builds its web page using the [JDocumentHTML](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocumentHTML/11.1) class. The thing is that the file that defines [JDocumentHTML](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocumentHTML/11.1) also imports the [JModuleHelper](http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/11.1). So when mod_acepolls is running by the web interface, then the [JModuleHelper](http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/11.1) is already imported.

The simplest solution to this is to import [JModuleHelper](http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/11.1) in *finder_indexer.php* (the file I guess you run using CLI/Cron). Find the lines that already does some importing (about line 45) and insert the following:

```
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
```

Its important to remember that this might break if you upgrade the website.